# How to use Log.e() to log the values and check in the logcat whether they exists or empty in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat

I have to move from one activity to another activity while passing value.But it moves nothing to the other activity.As a result I have to use Log.e() to check in the logcat if the value passes is empty or not.I have used the code below.But it is showing something strange.I got red lines which keep showing everytime I entered an item to move to next activity.

I have searched a lot but found nothing just introduction.Kindly help me how to solve this issue

**List Adapter**

```
 class ListAdapter (val context: Context, val list : ArrayList<SmsData>): BaseAdapter(){
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent,false)

        /*view.clickable.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity1::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)
        }*/
        list[position].senderName?.let{
            view.sender.text = it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
        }

        view.sms_sender.text = list[position].senderName

        view.sms_message.text = list[position].message

        view.sms_date.text = list[position].date.toString()

        view.clickable.setOnClickListener { View ->

            /*val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity1::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("address",list[position].senderName)
           Log.e("MainActivity1","show address")
                    context.startActivity(intent)*/

            if(list.isNullOrEmpty() || !list.contains(position) || list[position].senderName == null) {
                Log.e("MainActivity1","senderName was null or not found")
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity1::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("address",list[position].senderName)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        return  view


    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return list[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return list.size
    }
}
```

**Expected:**

Show something in the logcat which helps me to detect if value is passing or not.

**Actual**

I got these red lines as a result.
[image: Actual result in logcat]

Comment: if I've understood you right, and you're getting an error with that code, please add the error. If the problem is the output color, please clarify that and update your screenshot accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Log.e` is for error logging, that's why it shows up as red. use `Log.d` for debug or `Log.v` for verbose instead.

Here's all the log types : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log

> ASSERT Priority constant for the println method.
>
> DEBUG Priority constant for the println method; use Log.d.
>
> ERROR Priority constant for the println method; use Log.e.
>
> INFO Priority constant for the println method; use Log.i.
>
> VERBOSE Priority constant for the println method; use Log.v.
>
> WARN Priority constant for the println method; use Log.w.

furthermore, you should be printing this :

```
Log.e("MainActivity1",list[position].senderName)
```

or

```
Log.e("MainActivity1",list.size())
```

to see the size of the list or to check if it's null

---

OR , you can improve on this by doing something like this :

```
    if(list.isNullOrEmpty() || !list.contains(position) || list[position].senderName == null) {
    Log.e("MainActivity1","senderName was null or not found")
    }else{
    val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity1::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("address",list[position].senderName)
    context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

---

After OP posted adapter class, I realized it's an adapter of a model, so this will work :

```
    if(list.isEmpty() || list[position].senderName == null) {
    Log.e("MainActivity1","senderName was null or list empty")
    } else {
    val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity1::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("address",list[position].senderName)
    context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```